# Flutter Firebase Error(2020) - (Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug')

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

#### Error when adding firebase package

> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
> The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
> Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.21.0-9.2.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.1082], locale en-US)
 
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.49.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
```

### How to fix it

`android/app/build.gradle` add `multiDexEnabled true`

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Comment: which  plugin versions are u using?

Comment: @PeterHaddad, i updated the post with my flutter doctor. Just today the problem occurs, Some people posted today on our fb flutter community that they encounter that problem yesterday. So I decided to create fresh project with firebase packages and that happens. So i feel like sharing this if they might encounter the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the `minSdkVersion`:

```
minSdkVersion 15
```

to

```
minSdkVersion 23
```