# While I am running my flutter project I am unable to run it in emulator or mobile, it is showing error in debug console

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging, sdk

While I am trying to run my flutter project I am unable to run it in emulator or mobile, it is showing this error in the debug console:

```
Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\alian\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\be6d711c57b89887f4ceca287ebaa2f2\jetified-flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-241c87ad800beeab545ab867354d4683d5bfb6ce.jar.
Cannot parse result path string: 

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63918729/12789200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried deleting the `C:\Users\alian\.gradle\caches` folder and rerunning the build?

Answer (score 0):

Try with deleting Gradle folder in android path then,

- Clean and Rebuild your flutter's android project and wait for the build Successfull.